# XML or other markup to LaTeX?

Tags: macros, conversion, xml

In my university project I am doing software testing - planning, implementation, evaulation. All test documents have the format:

- General information
- Test categories
- Test cases
- Test implementation information
- Test run results
- Conclusion, errors

As the test subject (software) is about graphs, the test cases are also represented with images (one visio file for one word document). I also have to put some comments on classes and methods. Now I am storing a lot of redundant information in a quite unstructured format (for the computer). The main test results are also in trx files (which are XML and can be parsed easily with powershell). I would like to make this "system" less redundant. I would like to store the test document in a strongly structured format (like xml). My question is whether there is any XML to LaTeX converters? I don't want to use XSLT. Google did not help me this time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: With [`xmltex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xmltex) you can directly parse and evaluate XML from LaTeX.

Comment: as Stephen said you _could_ use xmltex, but despite having written xmltex I would always use XSLT for this. Why don't you want to use XSLT it is the ideal language for the job you describe.

Comment: See also [Is there some typesetting system that uses XML notation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11260) if you don't insist on LaTeX.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why you don't want to use XSLT? It's designed for precisely this kind of task, and it seems a trifle perverse to reject it out of hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use DocBook, and convert to LaTeX with Pandoc.

```
pandoc -f docbook -t latex yourfile.docbook
```

DocBook is pretty well documented.

As an alternative to a more structured format, Emacs org-mode can give you plenty of features in a text format, with many export options including LaTeX.